# limit point of a set under discrete topology

Tags: general-topology

I showed that $0$ is a limit point of the set $\{1/n\}$, where $n$ is any natural number, under the standard topology. 
Now I am curious if this holds in the discrete topology and indiscrete topology. I think it does because for discrete nothing changes, and for indiscrete $0$ is a limit point vacuously. Am I right?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the discrete topology, there are no limit points. The only thing close to a point is the point itself. That is the essence of the discrete topology.

(Note however, that the set $\{1/n\mid n\in {\bf N}\}$ *is* discrete itself in the standard topology. However, that does not imply that it has no limit points. Indeed, there are spaces with countable *dense* discrete subsets, but which are uncountable.)

On the other hand, you are right about indiscrete topology. It is the exact opposite: everything is close to everything else. So the set of limit points of any given nonempty set is simply the whole space, or the complement (in case of a singleton).

Comment: you mean that the set of limit points is the the whole underlying space itself right? not only the complement.

Comment: @weakmoons: No, I mean the complement. A point is by definition not its own limit point. There is a neighbourhood of $x$ such that there is  no point in $\{x\}$ other than $x$ itself.

Comment: In the topological definition of a limit set, it is possible that a set is its own limit. So in the standard topology on R, the limit set of a closed interval would be the whole interval itself. No?

Comment: @weakmoons: I see your point. I was thinking about singletons, but for other nonempty sets, every point is a limit point. I've also missed the case of empty sets. Now it's corrected.

Answer (score 3):

In the discrete topology, all points are isolated. So $0$ cannot be the limit point of any set, since it always has a neighborhood - $\{0\}$ - that does not contain any other points of the set.

In general, making a topology coarser will add limit points, while making it finer will remove limit points.